# Huge amount of Placemarks on MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, core-graphics, mapkit

i have a application, which is connected to a webservice, and it is getting realtime informations about something happened at some places.
The Information have a timestamp and Lat/Lon coordinates.
I store each of that datasets into a `NSMutableArray`. In some cases, there can be several thounsands (50.000) of datasets in it.
That all is working great. But now i want to have a `MKMap` on which i place each dataset as a small dot (6px diameter) on the desired location.
I have a function, that is called if a new message is placed in the array. Here i can put the new point to the map.

My question is now, when i use annotaions, the `MKMap` will be unusable due to the high amount of annotations. Every two seconds i want to redraw the points in the view area. I do this, because i want to change the colors of the points. Color from Yellow to brown depends on the age of the message.

What is the best method to do this ? What about a Core Graphics layer over the `MKMap` ?
And what about if i drag the map, or if i change the zoomlevel? I think, I need a redraw of the map then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the points, I would recommend just updated their `UIView` objects rather than re-adding them to the map for performance reasons.